# The iPhone cannot be backed because there is not enough iCloud Storage for that

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

Where can I determine what apps make the incredible size of backup?

[image]

As you can see there is almost 30GB free space, but I cannot perform a backup because there is not enough space **on iCloud**. Why?

**Using iOS 11, iPhone 6S Plus 128GB**

Under **Manage Storage** > **Backup** there is following screen:

[image]

My question is different to the marked one as duplicated, because:

- I have 50GB storage on iCloud including 30 gb free space
- using iOS 11
- my problem IS NOT about why backup still have 5GB, but why there is no space, even when backup is 20gb (what is rather impossible).

Comment: how many apps on your iphone?  Photos and music?

Comment: @Tetsujin it is not duplicated. Read my explanation.

Comment: The answer explaining how to clear your online space & potentially reduce what space is needed is the same. You're looking in the wrong place to check your current storage... General > iPhone storage, not iCloud > Manage.

Comment: My problem is not related to iphone storage at all

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily increase your iCloud storage ($1 per month) and do your backup. You can then check how big the backup is. I noted you have 128GB on your phone. If only a fraction of that is used it could be a lot. After your backup, you can reduce your icloud storage back to 50 GB to end the $1 per month charge.

Comment: Please, note, that I have already 50GB storage per month and there is 30GB free space;)

Comment: Yes, it was the answer;) I needed to upgrade my icloud account to 200 GB, then I was able to see what was the reason af a huge backup, then I downgraded an storage and now it is fine;)

Answer (score 1):

To determine what is being backed-up to iCloud:

- From the screen shown in the question, [Settings > Apple ID, iCloud > iCloud]
- Tap **Manage Storage**
- Scroll down to **Backup** and tap
- Select the desired device from the list [iPhone]
- Give the phone time to calculate the sizes of the backups

From there you can see what Apps are backing up data from the largest to the smallest backup size.

Comment: After manage storage > Backup, there is no list of devices. What should I do now?

Comment: this saved me, ty sir